# How to compile Coffeescript in visual studio 2013 express?

Tags: coffeescript, visual-studio-2013

I followed this,

1. Go download and install VS Web Essentials
2. Add a new Item to your project, pick CoffeeScript as the item type
3. Write your CoffeeScript code, when you build the project or Solution, it will create the JavaScript code.

But, it does not create any compiled JS file.

How can I compile coffeescript? Do I need to install node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried Web Essentials for VS yet because it's easier for me to just include the coffee-script.js file using a script tag and compile it using the browser.  I also console.log the compiled JavaScript output to the browser to see what it is generating. Here are a few examples using this technique:

https://github.com/jabdal/coffee-script-examples

Remarkably, it will sometimes find errors in the resultant JavaScript and go to the line with the error.

I'm guessing you could then send the JS back to the server and save that to a JS file (along with a checksum of the original coffeescript file). Then instead of compiling next time, you could include the JS file that is on the server if it is the same version (compare checksum before compiling on client).

I've read somewhere there is a .NET implementation of JavaScript that might work with the coffeescript compiler so that you could compile on the server without having to use Node but I don't think it would hurt to offload it on the client.  A nice way would be a runat="server" tag for script type="text/coffeescript" tag so that the server would replace the coffeescript tags with javascript tags along with the compiled code and also generate corresponding js files where there are coffee files.